# Connection fails (timeout) to SFTP server with correct private key (Golang)

Tags: go, sftp

I'm trying to write an sftp client in Golang. The owners of the server require connection using public/private keys. I have already sent them a public key (4096 bit) and got a username. To test the connection I user FileZilla with my private key - it worked fine. But my golang client does not work: ssh.Dial hangs forever or just aborts on ClientConfig timeout... Does anyone has any ideas what can be wrong with it (with my code or around it)? My code is bellow:

```
keyFile := filepath.Join(dir, "id_rsa")
pkBytes, err := os.ReadFile(keyFile)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
signer, err := ssh.ParsePrivateKeyWithPassphrase(pkBytes, []byte("mysecret"))
if err != nil {
    return err
}

username := "my_username"
sftpDir := "/home/upload/"

keyFile = filepath.Join(dir, "id_rsa.pub")
pkBytes, err = os.ReadFile(keyFile)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

hostKey, _, _, _, err := ssh.ParseAuthorizedKey(pkBytes)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

clientConfig := &ssh.ClientConfig{
    User:            username,
    Auth:            []ssh.AuthMethod{ssh.PublicKeys(signer)},
    HostKeyCallback: ssh.FixedHostKey(hostKey),
    Timeout:         10 * time.Second,
}

conn, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", "sftp.trustyou.com:22", clientConfig)
// here we stop or hang forever.... :-(
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("SSH DIAL FAILED:%v", err)
}
defer conn.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I can finally answer my own question: the code is Ok. The problem happens only on our customer' server which is located behind a firewall. So it is network settings that are responsible for this.
To make sure I changed the ClientConfig settings to ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey and ran it on my office computer. It connected successfully.

```
clientConfig := &ssh.ClientConfig{
    User:            h.UserName,
    Auth:            []ssh.AuthMethod{ssh.PublicKeys(t.signer)},
    HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(), // ssh.FixedHostKey(hostKey),
    Timeout:         15 * time.Second,
}
```

P.S. I know that my answer (and the question itself) now looks stupid comparing to some really creative issues here... Sorry about that. But this is how it works sometimes...

Comment: A network issue does not explain *"To test the connection I user FileZilla with my private key - - __it worked fine__"*. Either you accessed from a different host (not blocked by Firewall) or with a different protocol (FileZillla supports several)

Comment: Steffen, you are right. I used FileZilla on a different host. I know I must had guessed to check connection from that server but... Sorry about rising a stupid question.

Answer (score -1):

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/alessiosavi/GoGPUtils/helper"
    stringutils "github.com/alessiosavi/GoGPUtils/string"
    "github.com/alessiosavi/GoSFTPtoS3"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    log.SetFlags(log.LstdFlags | log.Lshortfile | log.Lmicroseconds)

    var sftpConf = &GoSFTPtoS3.SFTPConf{
        Host:     "localhost", // FIXME: Change host and user
        User:     "alessiosavi",
        Password: "",
        Port:     22,
        Bucket:   "bucket-ftp",
        Timeout:  50,
        PrivKey:  "",
    }
    // FIXME: Use your key
    file, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/home/alessiosavi/.ssh/mykey.pem")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    sftpConf.PrivKey = string(file)

    conn, err := sftpConf.NewConn()
    defer conn.Close()
    list, err := conn.List("/tmp")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    log.Println(helper.MarshalIndent(list))

}
```